# Hostname for IP address of LAN devices?

Tags: command-line, hostname

What commands look up the hostname of a LAN device at a given IP address? For example:

```
dig -x ip.address
nslookup ip.address
```

are not giving LAN device names, only registered domain names on the WAN.

Comment: Yeah it looks like the same question...with no effective answer before either.

Comment: Will you show the output of the command and an example of the output you were trying to get.